# Hive: Automatically GRANT SELECT to another user on table creation , in shared database

Tags: hive, authorization, role-base-authorization

I have a hive db 'common' where 5 users create tables (HDP2.1). Is it possible to automate GRANT SELECT on any new table created in this DB by user1 to role1 (not the entire DB).